# General planar graph $L(G)$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph. Show that if $G$ is planar and $3$-regular then the line-graph $L(G)$ corresponding to $G$ is also planar.

Considering small examples might help. I can find an embedding for the tetrahedron, for instance. I need to find a planar embedding for $L(G)$ by manipulating the planar embedding that I can find for $G$. So let $(\mathcal{P}, \Gamma)$ be a planar embedding for $G,$ where $\Gamma$ is a set of simple curves representing edges and $\mathcal{P}$ is a set of points representing vertices. Vertices of $L(G)$ are adjacent iff they share a common vertex. We think of the edges in $\Gamma$ as vertices in $L(G).$ For any pair of edges in $\Gamma$ with a common vertex, we connect them with an edge in $L(G).$ Since the degree of every vertex of the graph is $3$, around every vertex $v$ and the edges in $\Gamma$ are continuous, we can draw $3$ edges that do not intersect and connect all $3$ pairs of edges incident with $v$. We can then delete repeated edges so that there is exactly one of each edge. I think this yields a planar embedding of $L(G),$ but I'm not really sure how to justify this more formally; perhaps it's wrong?

Comment: I am interested in this question. Is this an exercise/known result? If so, could you provide a reference? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: @AustenFAN if you have an idea of how to solve it, let me know. I just remembered it from an old textbook; I forgot which one unfortunately.

Comment: Your proof looks mostly fine, if a bit skimping on details about why you can add the edges. If you're willing to use a strong result like Fary's Theorem, I think this is a lot easier to prove 'rigorously', because then you know (without delving into any topology at least) that your edges are not doing anything weird.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F%C3%A1ry%27s_theorem